# Get variable from Python to C# using pythonnet

Tags: python, variables, emgucv, python.net

I have simple python code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def show_img(path):
   img = cv2.imread(path)
   plt.imshow(img)
   plt.show()
```

And I call a func show_img() in C#:

```
// Initialize the Python engine
PythonEngine.Initialize();
// Load the Python script
dynamic opImageModule = PythonEngine.ModuleFromString("show_img",File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\slorate\\Desktop\\cv.py"));
// We call the Python function
dynamic imgOut = opImageModule.show_img("C:\\Users\\slorate\\Desktop\\py\\-6+5_Cut.bmp");
```

Q: How work with variable "img" from python in C#? Without saving image in python and using path. I just want get variable "img" and continue work with it in C#...

For example I have a case: recognise object on image in Python and get this recognised image in C#

I tried convert "dynamic" type into Emgu.CV.Mat.